# Error running setup:upgrade on live server in magento 2.2.4 I get Port must be configured within host parameter (like localhost:3306

Tags: php, sql, magento

When I run the following command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` in the root of my magento application I get the following errors;

```sh
root:/var/www/www-root/data/www/blessingcomputers.com# php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Port must be configured within host parameter (like localhost:3306)
```

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
                                           
[PDOException]                             
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Please assist how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and for me the solution was to change my host config variable from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, then it could connect.

Comment: Where to change this value?

Comment: In your `env.php` file, usually located in `app/etc/`.